# UIView not registering touch events when adding to sharedApplication's keyWindow

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, subclass, appdelegate

I have a UIView subclass called messageView which I call from the appDelegate like below

```
let mesgView = messageView(frame: CGRect(x: application.statusBarFrame.minX, y: application.statusBarFrame.minY+50.0, width: application.statusBarFrame.width, height: 75))

UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.addSubview(mesgView)
mesgView.window?.windowLevel = UIWindowLevelStatusBar+1
```

I call it like this because I need to show a view when the user is in the app and they receive a push notification.

in messageView,

```
override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    self.userInteractionEnabled = true
    self.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(messageView.didTap)))
}

func didTap() {
    print("tapped")
}
```

However, when tapping on mesgView it does not register a touch. I have also tried doing this with a transparent UIButton with no luck.

Where is the touch being registered?

Comment: Did you solve this? I have encountered the same problem...

Comment: @nullforlife I did not. I have another thought that would be to override touchesBegan/Moved/Ended and use a delegate to alert the main view that it was touched

Comment: @B L I actually solved this by adding a button with a clear background color that covered the whole view that was being viewed.

Comment: @nullforlife I tried that too but nothing

Comment: Do you have animations on it? Because I had to change how the animations worked since when the animation were rolling the view didn't receive any touches for some reason.

Comment: @nullforlife I tried it with and without animations. Same issue was occurring

Comment: I had same issue and removing animations made it work but I need animations so going to figure out. Please answer if anyone figured out. Thanks

Comment: I have the same issue. Tried the button and gestures. Nothing works

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your custom's view frame has correct value set. That was the case for me.
You might have your custom view clipsToBounds = false. That would be the reason you can see your view but taps won't register due to wrong frame